# ROS/Hydro installation error: library '-framework Cocoa' is neither a target nor built/installed properly

Tags: ros, rosdep-install, osx

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I tried to install ROS/Hydro in OS X10.9 with homebrew following with ：http://wiki.ros.org/hydro/Installation/OSX/Homebrew/Source

When I run `$ rosdep install --from-paths src --ignore-src --rosdistro hydro -y`, I got

```
 CMake Error at /Users/Baifan/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/share/pcl_ros/cmake/pcl_rosConfig.cmake:141 (message):
  Project 'depth_image_proc' tried to find library '-framework Cocoa'.  The
  library is neither a target nor built/installed properly.  Did you compile
  project 'pcl_ros'? Did you find_package() it before the subdirectory
  containing its code is included?
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /Users/Baifan/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:75 (find_package)
```

```
CMakeLists.txt:8 (find_package)
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/Users/Baifan/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/depth_image_proc/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
```

1. I installed **pcl-ros**. But I got error

```
 CMake Error at /usr/local/share/pcl-1.8/PCLConfig.cmake:47 (message):
  simulation is required but glew was not found
```

, then in **CMakeCache.txt** of **pcl_ros**, I replaced the line ` GLEW_INCLUDE_DIR:PATH=GLEW_INCLUDE_DIR-NOTFOUND` to

`GLEW_INCLUDE_DIR:PATH=/usr/local/Cellar/glew/1.11.0/include/GL` and replaced the line `GLEW_GLEW_LIBRARY:STRING=-framework GLEW`  to
`GLEW_GLEW_LIBRARY:FILEPATH=/usr/local/Cellar/glew/1.11.0/lib/libGLEW.dylib`.
It seems **pcl-ros** installed successfully.

2)I found there is find_package(PCL) in **CMakeLists.txt** of **depth_image_proc**.

So I don't know how to fix **'-framework Cocoa'** library problem. Can you help me?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/208788/ros/hydro-installation-error:-library-%27-framework-cocoa%27-is-neither-a-target-nor-built/installed-properly/) by [Whitesail](https://answers.ros.org/users/22342/whitesail/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2015-05-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I fixed the problem by replacing the line
`GLEW_COCOA_LIBRARY:STRING=-framework Cocoa`   to
`GLEW_COCOA_LIBRARY:FILEPATH= /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Cocoa.framework`  in **CMakeCache.txt** of **pcl_ros**.

---

Originally posted by [Whitesail](https://answers.ros.org/users/22342/whitesail/) with karma: 16 on 2015-05-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0